# Including library call in R function documentation

Tags: r

Does anyone know if there is any reason to not include `library(package)` in `package` `@examples`? Does it affect the checks in some way?
The reason to include this is that online documentation (e.g. pkgdown output)
 doesn't contain `library(package)` in the beginning and thus copied code fails (and users complain). I've never seen any contraindications to do so. Are there are any?

Comment: If you put it `library(package)` in your examples does it throw an error for users who do not have that specific package installed?

Comment: Obviously, yes, it will throw an error, but it's not a matter of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would be fairly harmless to do that, but it looks weird, because the R help system is set up so that you don't need it.  If you run

```
example(foo)
```

you'll get an error if the package isn't attached, and if you run

```
example(foo, package = "mypackage")
```

then it will make sure that `library(mypackage)` has been called.

It also will tend to mislead new users (the ones who don't know about `library(mypackage)`) and make them think that it is needed to be called frequently, rather than just once.  It may even make it look as though *you* believe that, undermining your credibility.

So I'd advise against it.